Can I simulateTransaction with arbitrary token balance amounts?
Is it prossible to pretent having infinite arbitrary token balances during simulateTransaction so that I could go through tests for swaps?

No, with the current version of simulateTransaction, you don't have the ability to override account data.
On the other hand, you can probably find huge holders of the tokens that you want to trade, and simulate using those accounts.
